# Reading a Git repository, without Git

Tags: php, git, version-control

I'm researching the idea of building a super-small (preferably PHP) web app, which will serve (among other things) as a minimal front-end to a git repository.

**Any library/article for reading a git repository** (".git" folder) **without having to execute the "git" process?** I'm looking for an API to manage a git repository. I'm only interested in basic functions, such as reading last commits (name of commiter, commit note, date), displaying and traversing branches...

Thanks,
ANaimi

Comment: Here's a good article on the subject: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-Objects

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Would [this](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/technical/api-index.html) (git API documents) be of any help?

Here's a list of resources about extending php (i.e. to to provide wrappers around other library code):

- [extending php - an overview](http://www.whenpenguinsattack.com/2006/11/15/how-to-write-php-extensions/)
- [writing php extension modules in C](http://www.php.net/~wez/extending-php.pdf)
- [PHP extension writing](http://talks.somabo.de/200707_extension_writing.pdf)
- [writing extensions](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/20/0/0)
- [Practical PHP Programming:Writing extensions](http://www.ipbwiki.com/Practical_PHP_Programming:Writing_extensions)
- [Extending PHP: examples](http://people.apache.org/~nabeel/php/examples/index.html)
- [Writing a PHP Extension](http://talks.php.net/show/extending-php-apachecon2003)
- [Extension Writing Part I: Introduction to PHP and Zend](http://devzone.zend.com/node/view/id/1021)
- [Zend API: Hacking the Core of PHP](http://de.php.net/manual/en/internals2.ze1.zendapi.php)
- [PHP at the Core: A Hacker's Guide to the Zend Engine](http://de.php.net/manual/en/internals2.php)
- [Creating a PHP5 Extension with MS VC++ 2005](http://blog.slickedit.com/?p=128)
- [Writing a PHP Extension (C++)](http://www.cstruter.com/articles/replyarticle.aspx?ContentID=151)

Also, these would seem relevant, too:

- [git-php](http://code.google.com/p/git-php/)
- [git library?](http://aseigo.blogspot.com/2009/01/git-library.html)
- [Pure-Python Git Library](https://launchpad.net/dulwich)
- [Git library?](http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2008/4/28/1638484)
- [libgit2 - a true git library](http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2008/10/31/3880864) & [libgit2 source code at GitHub](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2)
- [php-git, a libgit2 binding](https://github.com/libgit2/php-git)
- [ActionScript3 git library](http://thillerson.blogspot.com/2008/05/as3-git-library.html)

Comment: git API documents link is now broken :-(

Comment: And now it is no longer broken :-)

Answer (score 6):

You may also want to check out the [Cgit](http://hjemli.net/git/cgit/) project since they've done something similar (except they build their own git library -- also to avoid running `git` directly).

There's [JGit](http://www.jgit.org/), a pure Java implementation, that may be useful to you.

Answer (score 3):

Try also [glip](http://fimml.at/#glip), a pure php implementation of git, which was extracted from eWiki.

Answer (score 2):

I think that best start in such case  could be [Interfaces Frontends And Tools](http://git.or.cz/gitwiki/InterfacesFrontendsAndTools) page on Git Wiki.
You can find there link to [eWiki](http://fimml.at/en/ewiki) ([github](http://github.com/patrikf/ewiki)) which supposedly uses native (in PHP) access to Git.

Comment: Yes actually that's what i'm doing right now. Looking at eWiki's code.