# git: getting my website to fetch content from Github

Tags: git, github, github-api

I'm somewhat new to git and github, but I'm wondering if the following is possible.

I have several .xml files that I'm version controling in a separate repo and what I would really like is for the website to be able to call up ("pull" into a designated directory on the server) the most recent version (and eventually older versions) of the file from the github repo.

Is the GitHub API pull something that might allow me to do this?

Would I need Git installed on my hosting server? Are most hosting service able to provide this?

Am I way off base here?

Comment: What is the language you use as a backend for you site? You can make it easily either by using a git library in your backend or by calling git commands directly from the backend. I would say that if you use the second option (git commands) you need to have git installed on the server, if you use the other alternative it is not mandatory.

Comment: I'm using PHP. Sorry forgot to mention that - Can you recommend a git library for PHP?

Comment: Try the list of the first answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/645814/reading-a-git-repository-without-git But I haven't tried them personally, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the API to get the latest version of a file - you can just use the GitHub raw URL for the file.

```
https://github.com/<username>/<projectname>/raw/master/<filepath>
```

For instance, here's the `README.md` file from one of my personal projects:

```
https://github.com/ayust/pluss/raw/master/README.md
```

You can substitute a commit SHA, tag name, or different branch name for `master` to get a different version.

Comment: just a quick edit: the url listed here actually redirects to: `https://raw.github.com/<username>/<projectname>/master/<filepath>` So if you really should use this url if you need to access the file directly.