# Best Method/Language for doing a Git Pull from Web Browser

Tags: php, git, webserver

I'm creating a service that will allow users to deploy updates to a server from a web browser using git. Ex: Click the 'Deploy' button and its run a git command. Right now the proposed language is PHP and the proposed solution is doing something like:

```
<?php
exec('git pull origin master');
?>
```

Easy yes, but I'm not sure it is the best method or what are its drawbacks. So my question is, what language/methods should I use to allows users to pull down onto their servers from a web browser? Whats the best language for interfacing with the server? Does it even matter?

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't matter at all. Ideally it should be a language you / your team are strong in.

But doing an "exec" is not the way to do it!

Use a library. E.g. try this:

[Reading a Git repository, without Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645814/reading-a-git-repository-without-git)