# Get the last version's date on git

Tags: php, git, version-control

I want to get the last version's date for a project on git... Meaning the date of the last change for projects like:

- https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/checkout
- https://code.google.com/p/qextserialport/source/checkout

Im not familiar with git, and after many searches I tried this:

```
$ git --version
git version 1.8.1.2    
$ git log -1 --format="%ct" http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

The code is inteneded to be executed from php through [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), and the returned date will be formatted later...

Comment: As far as I know, Github and code.google.com are two completely different things.

Comment: @GaijinJim the question is about git in general, not about a source control hosting provider.

Comment: Your posted command still tries to access code.google.com using git. Furthermore: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/645814/reading-a-git-repository-without-git) is something to read, most notably: [git-php](https://code.google.com/p/git-php/).

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible for git to connect to a server and check its log. You need to either clone the repo and get the date with `git log -1 --format="%ci"` or use an API provided by the host, Github has an API not sure about google code but you could parse the site to get the information.

Answer (score 0):

This will show you the latest commit on each branch, so the first in the list is the latest commit for the entire project:

```
git for-each-ref --sort=-committerdate refs/heads/ --format="%(authordate) %(refname)"
```

It'll be up to you to use PHP to handle the output.

Comment: No problem from the php side, I'll handle it... I'm just struggling making the correct command to fetch the git's infos... So, would you please adapt your command to work with my first example `https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/checkout`... I still can't get it work :>

Comment: @Enissay I don't see how you'll be able to query a remote repo hosted on a website without an HTTP API exposed. You'll need to check it out or find that API.